# Divisibility of binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Let $p$ be a prime number and $q\in \{1,\dots,p-1\}$.  Prove that $\tbinom{2p-q-1}{p-q} \equiv 0\pmod {p}$

However, I have no idea how to prove this.

Would be thankful for solution.

Comment: What does your notation mean?  Did you possibly  mean $\binom {2p-q-1}{p-q}$?

Comment: The numerator must contain $p$ and the nominator can't. Just write it down then you will understand the answer from @tong_nor.

Comment: @lulu, Yes, I did. This is a notation of binomial coefficient.

Comment: Well, it's not a standard notation.  Normally $C^n_r=\binom nr$.

Comment: @lulu, In Russian universities and books it is a standard notation :)

Comment: Never knew that.  I suggest editing your post to make it clear...I expect most readers here will interpret it the way I did.

Comment: @lulu, Also $\tbinom{n}{k}=C_n^k$

Comment: As I say, that is not the standard notation in English speaking countries.  As you can see from the posted solution below, your notation is going to confuse your readers.

Comment: @lulu, I've corrected it.

Comment: Given the non-standard interpretation, the claim is trivial.  $p<2p-q-1$ so $p$ divides the numerator.  $p>p-q$ and $p>2p-q-1-(p-q)=p-1$ so $p$ does not divide the denominator.

Comment: @lulu, Yes indeed. It turns out to be easy fact :(

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $C^n_k=\binom{n}{k}$:

$2p-q-1>p-q$, so you just have $C^{p-q}_{2p-q-1}=0$ $\dots$

---

Also $C_{p-q}^{2p-q-1}=\frac{(2p-q-1)!}{(p-q)!(p-1)!}$ is divisible by $p$, since $p-q,\ p-1\in\{0,\dots,p-1\}$ and $2p-q-1\ge p$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is so easy however I did not think in that way :(